# PHP loop within a loop, option selected?

Tags: php, loops, select, html-select

Using PHP I echo out table rows in a loop like this:

```
<?php
/* SQL STUFF */

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($select_courseelements)) {
   echo "<tr>\n";
    echo "<td>".$row['scpe_name']."</td>\n";
    echo "<td>".$row['scpe_days']."</td>\n";
   echo "</tr>\n";
  }
```

Now I would like to include a `<select>` element with 5 predefined `<option>` values inside a `<td>` running with the loop. The option `value`s will be 1 to 5. 
There is also a column inside the `$row` loop that holds a value of 1 to 5 (`$row['scpe_grades_status']`).

Each time this value is equal to the one in the `<select>` I want it to change it to `selected='selected'`.

Would this be possible?

My `<select>` will look something like this when it's being run in the loop:

```
echo "<td>\n";
echo "<select id='elements_grade'>\n";
        echo "<option value='1'>Registrerad</option>\n";
        echo "<option value='2'>Ej påbörjad</option>\n";
        echo "<option value='3'>Pågående</option>\n";
        echo "<option value='4'>Godkänd</option>\n";
        echo "<option value='5'>Deltagit</option>\n";
        echo "<option value='6'>Ej deltagit</option>\n";
echo "</select>\n";
echo "</td>\n";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$array = array('Registrerad' => 1, 'Ej påbörjad' => 2, 'Pågående' => 3, 'Godkänd' => 4, 'Deltagit' => 5, 'Ej deltagit' => 6);

foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {
    if ($value == $row['scpe_grades_status'])
        echo '<option value="'.$value.'" selected>'.$key.'</option>';
    else
        echo '<option value="'.$value.'">'.$key.'</option>';
}
```

Something like that?

Comment: Thank's for the answer. There seems to be something wrong with your code though. It only generates one `<option>` with all array values on one single line

Comment: what if i want the selected data ? from db

Answer (score 7):

Sure, build the values from a loop. and you can compare the values from that part.

```
for($i = 1; $i<=5; $i++) {
   echo "<option value='$i'";
   echo ($row['scpe_grades_status'] == $i) ? " selected='selected'": "";
   echo ">...."</option>"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a

```html
<br>
```

after each

```html
</option>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).