# How make drop-down in php have the option DB value as selected in html template

Tags: php, while-loop, connection

I have a drop-down in html which is being rendered from php template.
I can edit drop-down choice which takes usernames from DB, but how make it "selected" (what I have choose before) before editing?

Code for the template is below.

```
        $result = $conn->query("select username from users");
    echo "<html>";
    echo "<body>";
    echo "<select name='workers' >";
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                  unset($username);
                  $username = $row['username'];
    echo '<option value=" '.$username.'"  >'.$username.'</option>';}
    echo "</select>";
    echo "</body>";
    echo "</html>";
    ?>
```

Please help!

Comment: They are mega tons of tutorials out there...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP loop within a loop, option selected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071081/php-loop-within-a-loop-option-selected)

Answer (score 0):

You need to give to name to select tag and get that as that name like :

```
<?php
       $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname) or die ('Cannot connect to db');

            $result = $conn->query("select username from users");
        echo "<html>";
        echo "<body>";
        echo "<select name='drpdown'>";
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            unset($username);
            $username = $row['username'];
            echo '<option value=" '.$username.'"  >'.$username.'</option>';
        }
        echo "</select>";
        echo "</body>";
        echo "</html>";
    ?>
```

get the post variable like :

```
print_r($_POST['drpdown']);
```